# Ace Editor JSON format check not work in "localhost://"

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

This is my code in "file://":

[image: my code image. click and see]

It works. But when I put it on the "127.0.0.1".

[image]

There was an error. GET http://localhost:8080/worker-json.js 404 (Not Found)

Comment: what tool do you use to compile the require and exports in the second image to something that browsers understand?  you need to configure it in a way that worker-json.js file can be loaded in the web worker.

Comment: vue.js + webpack + Babel. If I require the worker-json.js file, it turns out that ' Can't resolve 'ace/lib/es5-shim' .And I wonder why it is a get request ?

Comment: configuring it to work with webpack may be hard, as you need to serve worker-json.js as a separate file

Answer (score 1):

I've done the following and the problem fixed:

ace.config.set("workerPath", "assets/js/plugins/editors/ace/")

Edit: I was facing an issue with multiple web workers being created each time Angular view is created, so with a quick search I found also a fix to prevent Ace from creating web workers multiple times, here is my code to init the editor:

```js
  // Code running with Angular 4 CLI and WebPack
  updateSkecthCalcPanel() {
    const editor = ace.edit(this.canvasObject.sketchCalcEditor); // Selector name
    const aceSession = editor.getSession();
    ace.config.set("workerPath", "assets/js/plugins/editors/ace/") // Folder contain the worker
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
    editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
    editor.setOptions({ readOnly: true, maxLines: Infinity });
    aceSession.setMode("ace/mode/json");
    aceSession.setValue(js_beautify(JSON.stringify(this.sketchObject), { indent_size: 2 }));
    // Quick-fix that allows to omit ACE problem with loading workers
    ace.require("ace/edit_session").EditSession.prototype.$startWorker = function () { }
    
    // Fold Code
    window.setTimeout(function () {
      aceSession.foldAll(1, aceSession.getLength());
    }, 500);
  }
```